# Error Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'addCls' of null

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have an application that works perfectly but in the console I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'addCls' of null

But the application works correctly, because I sent this error if the application works?

---

I found the problem, but not how to fix it.
in my grid when I add:

```
features: [{ftype: 'grouping'}]
```

I start to get this error.

hopefully you can help me. 
regards

Comment: In chrome developer tools you can enable [pause on uncaught exception](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging?hl=de#pause-on-uncaught-exceptions) to see where and at what time you get this error.

Comment: here is where I launch the exception in ext-all-dev.js 

 if (item && me.isRowStyleFirst(item)) {
            me.getRowStyleTableEl(item).addCls(me.tableOverFirstCls);
        }

Comment: seems something to be with highlighting the first row in a table on mouseover. but I have no clue what could be the problem...
Do you use grouping? does the generated ExtJS table has this css class: `x-grid-table` ?

Comment: the problem is this row: `return (me.isGrouping ? Ext.fly(item) : this.el).down('table.x-grid-table');` which will return undefined if you have grouping enabled

Comment: because if I want to group and send me this error? 
as I can do to be able to group without me error?

Comment: could you please check if your rendered `table` has the `.x-grid-table` class?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted in the comment :

```
if (item && me.isRowStyleFirst(item)) {
    me.getRowStyleTableEl(item).addCls(me.tableOverFirstCls);
}
```

This code will throw that error if `me.getRowStyleTableEl(item)` is undefined. Grouping breaks the function `me.getRowStyleTableEl()`.
Change the code like this to omit the `.addCls`. Or adapt `.getRowStyleTableEl` to be compatible with grouping.

```
if (item && me.isRowStyleFirst(item) && me.getRowStyleTableEl(item)) {
    me.getRowStyleTableEl(item).addCls(me.tableOverFirstCls);
}
```